# How to detect broken symlinks in Go?

Tags: linux, go

I have tried opening the file with `ff, _ := os.Open("Filename")` and then running `ffi, _ := ff.Stat()`.

Which is the closest thing I could find that provides any details, but that doesn't seem to be following the symlinks.

What I'm really trying to do is extract the original file name (which is deleted) from the symlink.

I'm on a Linux machine.

Comment: Ok, I think I posted it too soon, `os.Readlink(filename)` does exactly this. But it returns in the format 'filename (deleted)', which is not an issue for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`os.Readlink(filename)` does it.